# Передача строки из Activity в Fragment, код которого находится в другом файле

Tags: android-fragment, activity, android, java

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с необходимостью отправить в Fragment строку, без которой просто никак. Покопался на StackOverflow - накопал такую вещь: в Activity это

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("URL", "");
FragmentClass fragment = new FragmentClass();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

а во Fragment'е вот это:

```
String srt = this.getArguments().getString("URL");
```

Но приложение падает, а в Logcat'е вижу NullPointerException. Других способов я не нашел. Как тогда передать строку?
p.s. заранее спасибо)

Comment: самое главное - на какой строке вы видите NullPointerException.    
Раскройте секрет...

Comment: В LogCat'е не вижу ни колонки, ни какого-либо другого места с номером строки  
    04-03 19:52:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(12975): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
Все сообщения подобного вида.

Comment: не может такого быть. выложите весь лог из логката

Comment: http://rghost.ru/private/53744782/553e373f877c9bd087184825dd794e27

Comment: ну вот же 

> com.example.entrypageparser.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:40)

что там происходит у вас?

Comment: Toast.makeText.... дальше не напишу, там была переменная str, видимо вот в чем дело. Удалил, запустил программу - работает как часы. Какое же я дерево)) пора учиться читать LogCat :))) Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не совсем понятно в какой момент у вас идет обращение, но вообще рекомендуют делать так:

```
// В активити
FragmentClass fragment = FragmentClass.newInstance(url);

// В классе  фрагемента
public static FragmentClass newInstance(String url){
  FragmentClass fragment = new FragmentClass();
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("URL", url);
  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
  return fragment;
}

//а дальше уже в onCreate, onActivityCreated и проч
String srt = this.getArguments().getString("URL");
```